# Check if terminal is IDLE

Tags: xtermjs

I am writing a "Compile and / or Run" plugin for Graviton (https://graviton.ml), a code editor providing a terminal with xtermjs.

Is there any way to check if the current terminal is IDLE?

By IDLE I mean at the bash / cmd prompt waiting for input.